# AssertionError and TypeError in Python

Tags: python

I have a few problems I can't get over even after a few days of working on it.

A `Toy` has no instance variables and one method, play, which returns the string `"Squeak!\n"` (with the exclamation mark and the capital `'S'`, without spaces, and with a newline at the end). The constructor for Toy (its `__init__` method) takes no parameter (except the usual self) and does nothing (so it can probably be omitted).

A `Dog` has one instance variable, its name, which must be provided as a parameter to the constructor. It has two methods:

`call(self, shout)` returns `True` if `shout` is exactly `"Here, n!"` (with the comma, the space and the exclamation mark, and no leading or trailing spaces), where `n` is the Dog's name. Otherwise, it returns `False`.
`play(self, toy, n)` produces the string `"Yip! "` (with the trailing space) concatenated with the the string returned by `toy.play()`. It returns this combination repeated n times, except if n is negative, it is the same as if it were 0. Clarification: "s" repeated 2 times is "ss". "s" repeated 0 times is "".

This is what i have:

```
class Toy:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def play(self):
        return "Squeak!\n"

class Dog:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def call(self, shout):
        self.shout = shout
        if self.shout == 'Here, ' + self.name + '!':
            return True
        return False

    def play(self, toy, n):
        self.toy = toy
        self.n = n
        if n <= 0:
            print('')
        else:
            for i in range(n):
                print('Yip ' + self.toy.play())
```

However, I get few errors such as this:

```
TestDog2.test_dog_fancy_toy

FAILURE: AssertionError
None != 'Yip! Ding, Dong!\n'
```

-

```
TestDog2.test_dog_play_once

FAILURE: AssertionError
None != 'Yip! Squeak!\n'
```

-

```
TestDog2.test_dog_play_zero_twice

ERROR: TypeError
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: When do you get those errors? What is the code that uses those classes? It was good idea to post what you have, but we'll need more to help you.

Comment: its python 3. and i have no idea why i get these kinds of errors.

Comment: I don't get half of what you have there... Did you instantiate a Dog and a Toy object?? And beware of capitalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Toy` class, the `play` method return a string while the `play` method of `Dog` returns nothing (It just print stuff).

When you're calling `dog.call()` you don't get the `'Yip ' + self.toy.play()` value in return. So the function returns `None` as expected and your assertion is wrong.
To fix that, you should return the value instead of print it.

For example, in your `Dog.call()` method:

```
if n <= 0:
    return ''
else:
    phrases = ['Yip ' + self.toy.play() for i in range(n)]
    return '\n'.join (phrases)
```

`phrases` is a list constructed [using list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It'll contains `n` elements, formed with the expression `'Yip ' + self.toy.play()`. You just have to join every elements with `\n` to create a new line after each phrase and you're done.

Comment: ahhhh thank you! so i would just have to change the 2 prints into returns def play(self, toy, n):?

Comment: Something like that, but be careful: the second print is in `for` loop. You may need to get each string and return the concatenation. With a comprehension list for example: `return '\n'.join (['Yip ' + self.toy.play() for i in range(n)])`

Comment: hmm i think i have lost you there. i have not learned to use "join" in class. could you write out the code for the part that u have explained to me?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Toy:
    def play(self):
        return "Squeak!\n"

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def call(self, shout):
        if shout == 'Here, ' + self.name + '!':
            return True
        return False

    def play(self, toy, n):
        if n <= 0:
            print('')
        else:
            for i in range(n):
                print('Yip ' + toy.play())

dog = Dog("Spot") # Spot the dog
toy = Toy()

assert(toy.play() == "Squeak!\n")
assert(dog.call("Here, {0}!".format('Spot'), 'Here, Spot!')
```

Not sure exactly what your question is but that may help slightly?

Really we need more information to be able to help you here.